# Docker - connecting to an open port in a container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

I'm new to docker and maybe this is something I don't fully understand yet, but what I'm trying to do is connect to an open port in a running docker container. I've pulled and run the rabbitmq container from hub (https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/). The rabbitmq container should uses port 5672 for clients to connect to.

After running the container (as instructed in the hub page):

```
$ docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Now what I want to do is telnet into the open post (it is possible on a regular rabbitmq installation and should be on a container as well).

I've (at least I think I did) gotten the container IP address using the following command:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

And the result I got was `172.17.0.2`. When I try to access using `telnet 172.17.0.2 5672` it's unsuccessful.

The address `172.17.0.2` seems strange to me because if I run `ipconfig` on my machine I don't see any interface using `172.17.0.x` address. I do see `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT)` using the following ip: `10.0.75.1`. Is this how it is supposed to be?

If I do port binding (adding `-p 5672:5672`) then I can telnet into this port using `telnet localhost 5672` and immidiatly connect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: On what operating system are you running Docker?

Comment: @larsks Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, you need port binding in order to achieve the result you need because you are running the application over the default bridge network (on Windows i guess).

From the [official docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)

> Containers connected to the same user-defined bridge network automatically expose all ports to each other, and no ports to the outside world. [...]
>    If you run the same application stack on the default bridge network, you need to open both the web port and the database port, using the -p or --publish flag for each. This means the Docker host needs to block access to the database port by other means.

Later in the [rabbitmq](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) hub there is a reference to a Management Plugin which is run by executing the command

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Which exposes the port 8080 used for management which I think is what you may need.
You should also notice that they talk about clusters and nodes there, maybe they meant the container to be run as a service in a swarm (hence using the overlay network and not the bridge one).

Hope I could help somehow :)

Comment: Thanks. That what I figured I had to do. I thought there might be something else I was missing, or a way to open ports on the container itself.